# Variables when requiring a NPM package

Tags: node.js, variables, nodes

I see a lot of NPM packages using `let` or `var`.

e.g: `var firebase = require('firebase');`

My inner OCD suggest these should always be defined as `const` variables.

Can anyone give a final answer on how these should be declared?

Comment: Many examples were created before ES6 when `const` is introduced. Nowadays always prefer `const`

Comment: You should ideally define a constant as such but we can never be too sure sometimes if this is the case, what if our object crashes or needs to suddenly reload in unique cases? I'd say you can't go wrong using either or, as long as you know your scoping correctly. Let is now more preferred to that of Var, and const hangs around for the ride if you choose not to let on everything... lol

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to create as `const` anything that you are not going to change the value. Since you're not going to change firebase object, you should import it to a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js uses commonJS module. `let` and `const` is ES6 javascript syntax for declaring variables.

So requiring a module is usually declared with `const`

```
const express = require('express')
```